# Converting a PDF slide show to a video file

Tags: conversion, imovie

I have a [LaTeX Beamer presentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer/) that I output into a PDF slide show. I want to turn into a video file (with the ability to add sound later) so that I can generate animations from Beamer . How can one do this? I've tried importing the PDF to iMovie, but the quality of the frames drops dramatically.

Comment: What are the contents of the PDF? Do you have access to the original material used to create the PDF?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman The PDF file was made in the LaTeX document class Beamer. I have the .tex file from which the slides come from. My goal is to use Beamer for frame-by-frame animations.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the presentation to a series of image files. The classic image format for that is a [TARGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) sequence. But you can use any format that your LaTeX tool chain can output and a video generator can import. For generating the image sequence, there are [several vector and raster formats](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats#Convert_to_image_formats) that LaTeX can export. You can then use ffmpeg to [turn the image sequence into video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow).

As a reminder, be sure to set the [aspect ratio of your presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14336/latex-beamer-presentation-package-169-aspect-ratio) appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the PDF file to PNGs (use density 144 for double the size):

```
convert -density 72 in.pdf out-%04d.jpg
```

Then import the images in any decent video editor, add a sound track, fine tune the result and export/render the video.